# manage multiple conditions and rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have these urls:

```
https://www.example.com/photo-events/photo-exhibition.php?id=1&name=nameexhibit
https://www.example.com/photographers/photographer.php?id=1&name=john-doe
```

I need change it in this way:

```
https://www.example.com/1/nameexhibit
https://www.example.com/1/john-doe
```

I added in my .htaccess this code:

```
#RULE 1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /photo-events/photo-exhibition\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /photo-events/photo-exhibition.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

#RULE 2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /photographers/photographer\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /photographers/photographer.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It works for the first rule but not for the second. Nothing happens on the photographer.php page, as if the server ignored the second rule.

How is it possible to cumulate Rewrite rules?
Any help would be really appreciated.